# How to batch create icon webfonts in windows from SVG files

Tags: windows, svg, fonts, webfonts, typography

In the past I've used tools such as [Font Custom](http://fontcustom.com/) and [IcoMoon](http://icomoon.io/) to create webfonts for use in various web applications used much like one would used [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/).

However there does not seem to be a solution that runs natively under windows. With Font Custom relying on libraries not available on windows, and IcoMoon not providing a batch / local way of doing things.

Is there a good way to do this on Windows, or does a solution not yet exist?

Bonus points if it can be done via Grunt or a Visual Studio build step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s [grunt-webfont](https://github.com/sapegin/grunt-webfont) (you need to use the `node` engine on Windows).

Comment: Excellent find, I did not come across a windows compatible option in my original search.